# Jquery.each throwing length is null or not an object

Tags: jquery, json

I have a Piece of code in JS to loop a JSON using Jquery each function. it's showing error as *length is null or not an object*.

```
var  claimJSONString = '{"claimJSON": [' + jsonString + ']}';
    //alert(claimJSONString);
      J.each(claimJSONString.claimJSON, function (i, v) {
        alert("v::" + v.tranID);
});
```

claimJSONString alerts as :

```
{
"claimJSON": [
    {
        "tranID": "12581",
        "a": "0",
        "b": "0",
        "c": "0",
        "d": "0"
    }
]
}
```

Also tried

```
J.each(jsonString, function (i, v) {
        alert("v::" + v.tranID);
});
```

where jsonString is 
    {
        "tranID": "12581",
        "a": "0",
        "b": "0",
        "c": "0",
        "d": "0"
    }
now the error is Object Expected.

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I am close to tearing my hair out. Please Help!
P.S.S Jquery Newbie

Comment: a json string is not a javascript object. you need to parse the json first. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse JSON Object from json string, use `jQuery.parseJSON()` or `JSON.parse()` methods, see below sample code

```
var  claimJSONString = jQuery.parseJSON('{"claimJSON": [' + jsonString + ']}');
```

And in `each` loop use `claimJSONString.claimJSON[0]` because your object in `[0]` index

```
J.each(claimJSONString.claimJSON[0], function (i, v) {
       alert("v::" + v.tranID);
});
```